# Window background black color when stylised

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, styles

I'm trying to apply the following background brush to a `NavigationWindow` :

```
<NavigationWindow.Background>
    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                                ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
</NavigationWindow.Background>
```

There is nothing currently besides this setter in the `NavigationWindow` element
body, I'm trying to work it out in a fresh project. The designer shows the proper coloring, but during runtime it becomes a lot darker than it should be:

This is how it's supposed to look and also how the designer properly displays it:

[image]

And this is how it looks during runtime:

[image]

I have tried to apply the same brush to a `Page` element and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your black color is 100% transparent and the background is black showing through at run time. In the designer you checkered white background is showing. You can prove that two way. First set Visual Studio to be in dark mode. Second change the NavigationWindow to `Background=Transparent`. You will see at run time it has a black background. On the other hand setting the background transparent on a page results in a white background.

Try using all opaque colors. Something like this:

```
<NavigationWindow.Background>
    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                            ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF4B4B4B"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
</NavigationWindow.Background>
```

Comment: There is no source for page, so there is no page to set a background to transparent and even if there is, that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Don't you see in your example snips how the designer canvas (checkered background) is showing through the transparent background of your window? At run time the black background simply shows through and looks different than the designer canvas. Try setting AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" for your window and run it. That should give you a better idea of what is actually happening.

Comment: Use all opaque colors for your gradient. #FF??????, instead of #00??????